# Image load lags when changing src on <img> tag in React

Tags: javascript, html, image, reactjs

I wrote a gallery like component that takes an array of objects in the format:

```
{
  ...
  title: string,
  url: string (the image url)
  ...
}
```

The gallery has a next button that lets you iterate through the array, displaying the data like title and showing the image in an  tag. While the text fields display instantly, the img tag lags a bit, showing the previous image for a second or two, and then showing the next.

Any idea how I can prevent this? Or at least get the first image to disappear immediately?

Comment: You could create a function that clears the elements before it loads the next one.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of resolving this, ranging in complexity and elegance. Simplest way I can think of is: change the src to something that will load instantly, then change it to the new img. You can use base64 transparent gif (which is like an image embedded in code) - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/base64-encode-of-1x1px-transparent-gif/

Comment: Wouldn't that cause a flicker - making the transition look bad? We have a bigger image that seems to load instantly. Any idea what actually might be causing the problem??

Thanks for the response!